# CreateCriteria sorting on two columns combined

Tags: nhibernate, sorting, fluent-nhibernate, createcriteria

```
SELECT [quantity ]
      ,[price]
FROM [dbo].[orderItem]
ORDER BY (quantity  * price) DESC
```

How should I write a CreateCriteria to generate SQL like the example above?

Answer (score 0):

Base on the fragment, I guess, that you've already done all the mappings. You also would have criteria similar to this snippet:

```
var criteria = session
  .CreateCriteria<OrderItem>()  // class with properties quantity, price ...
  .AddOrder(?) // how to append the order
  ;
var list = criteria.List<OrderItem>(); // Sorted list of OrderItems
```

The only missing point is the `OrderBy`. Thanks NHibernate extensibility, we can create our own `Order` object, and the when building the `Criteria`, we can call `.AddOrder(CustomOrder...)` Here is the code:

```
public class CustomOrder : Order
{
    public CustomOrder(string propertyName, bool ascending) 
        : base(propertyName, ascending) { }

    public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria
                                        , ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    {
        var sqlString = new SqlString(propertyName);
        return sqlString.Append(this.ascending ? " asc" : " desc");
    }
}
```

So, now we can put it all together:

```
var criteria = session
  .CreateCriteria<OrderItem>() 
  .AddOrder(new CustomOrder("(quantity  * price)", false)
  ;
var list = criteria.List<OrderItem>(); // Sorted list of OrderItems
```

Comment: Great to hear that! Good luck with NHiberante ;)